# ¿Cómo utilizar correctamente la api rest de woocomerce con una autenticación?

Tags: api, rest, woocommerce, postman

Estoy intentado utilizar la api de woocomerce pero al testear un endpoint en postman el resultado que me devuelve es este

{
"code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
"message": "Lo siento, no puedes listar recursos.",
"data": {
"status": 401
}
}
Este es el endpoint al que estoy tratando de acceder: https://petplacestore.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers
he hecho lo que dice la documentación y agregué las claves a la url pero aún así no me funciona, agradecería si alguien me pudiera ayudar.

Comment: estas traspasándole el API KEY? recuerda que sin eso no puedes hacer peticiones, puedes encontrar mas detalles sobre como generar el API KEY aquí:  http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#rest-api-keys

Comment: Si bro, lo estoy haciendo de esta manera https://petplacestore.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers?consumer_key=ck_xxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxx

Comment: He resuelto mi problema, mi solución fue que tuve que activar unos plugins que me estaban generando problemas a la hora de hacer la autenticación con la api key

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente.

https://petplacestore.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers

https://petplacestore.com/index.php/wp-json/wc/v3/customers

Saludos

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente tu respuesta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/340891)